# Max payload size for post request and Get response for SpringBoot Rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest

Is there any max size for send post payload ?

Actually, I have a service which send a json payload to another micro-service, In side of JSON payload, there is a filed which hold encoded String (basically i have converted file into encoded String and set it into that payload field value).

File size is not fixed, So i am curious about it, is there any max size support for Post json payload ?

I know spring-boot have following properties for set max size for file upload.

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size
```

But as i mentioned i am not upload file, i am convert file into encoded string and send this string with json payload.

So how can i set the max size support for post request.

Also In another scenario I am hitting a Get request to micro-service and then this micro service return a large payload,is there any limitation of receive payload size?

Comment: did you find an answert to this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends, not only in spring configuration as you've pointed, but also in server configuration.

Most servers have a post request loadout limit. For example in tomcat you can configure it with the "maxPostSize" property. Quoting from the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes):

```
The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the container FORM URL parameter parsing. 
The limit can be disabled by setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes).
```